# ASDM unable to launch device manager from

Tags: security, cisco-asa, java

I can't access to my `Cisco asa 5505` from my `Windows 7 64bit`.

The problem is that i can connect on it using the `ASDM` from another PC (`WinXP 32bit`), and i can connect using my `win7 64bit` to another `Cisco ASA5505`.

I guesse this a `java`/`windows` security problem.

I have disabled my `Win 64 bit` `firewall`, but no success.

I get many `jdk` and `jre` installed on my `win7 64bit`:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre6\
C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.6.0_41\

C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_41
```

I tried also to modify the `java` path into link of `ASDM`, for example:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre6\bin\javaw.exe" -Xms64m -Xmx512m -Dsun.swing.enableImprovedDragGesture=true -classpath lzma.jar;jploader.jar;asdm-launcher.jar;retroweaver-rt-2.0.jar com.cisco.launcher.Launcher
```

or

```
"C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\bin\javaw.exe" -Xms64m -Xmx512m -Dsun.swing.enableImprovedDragGesture=true -classpath lzma.jar;jploader.jar;asdm-launcher.jar;retroweaver-rt-2.0.jar com.cisco.launcher.Launcher
```

Here is log of `ASDM`:

```
    Java Web Start 1.6.0_41
Utilisation de la version JRE 1.6.0_41-b02 Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM
Répertoire d'accueil de l'utilisateur = C:\Users\my_session_name
----------------------------------------------------
c:   effacer la fenêtre de la console
f:   finaliser les objets de la file d'attente de finalisation
g:   libérer la mémoire
h:   afficher ce message d'aide
m:   imprimer le relevé d'utilisation de la mémoire
o:   déclencher la consignation
p:   recharger la configuration du proxy
q:   masquer la console
r:   recharger la configuration des politiques
s:   vider les propriétés système et déploiement
t:   vider la liste des threads
v:   vider la pile des threads
0-5: fixer le niveau de traçage à <n>
----------------------------------------------------
Application Logging Started at Sat Apr 13 18:04:26 GMT+01:00 2013
---------------------------------------------
java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.doConnect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.connect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.net.proxy.AbstractAutoProxyHandler.getJSFileFromURL(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.net.proxy.AbstractAutoProxyHandler.init(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.net.proxy.DynamicProxyManager.reset(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.net.proxy.DeployProxySelector.reset(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at com.cisco.launcher.ClassUtil.a(Unknown Source)
    at com.cisco.launcher.ClassUtil.initExecutionEnvironment(Unknown Source)
    at com.cisco.launcher.s.if(Unknown Source)
    at com.cisco.launcher.Launcher.main(Unknown Source)
Local Launcher Version = 1.5.56
Local Launcher Version Display = 1.5(56)
OK button clicked
Trying for ASDM Version file; url = https://192.168.1.254/admin/
javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Unrecognized SSL message, plaintext connection?
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.InputRecord.handleUnknownRecord(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.InputRecord.read(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.afterConnect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at com.cisco.launcher.y.a(Unknown Source)
    at com.cisco.launcher.y.if(Unknown Source)
    at com.cisco.launcher.r.a(Unknown Source)
    at com.cisco.launcher.s.do(Unknown Source)
    at com.cisco.launcher.s.null(Unknown Source)
    at com.cisco.launcher.s.new(Unknown Source)
    at com.cisco.launcher.s.access$000(Unknown Source)
    at com.cisco.launcher.s$2.a(Unknown Source)
    at com.cisco.launcher.g$2.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Trying for IDM. url=https://192.168.1.254/idm/idm.jnlp/
javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Unrecognized SSL message, plaintext connection?
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.InputRecord.handleUnknownRecord(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.InputRecord.read(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.afterConnect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(Unknown Source)
    at com.cisco.launcher.w.a(Unknown Source)
    at com.cisco.launcher.s.for(Unknown Source)
    at com.cisco.launcher.s.new(Unknown Source)
    at com.cisco.launcher.s.access$000(Unknown Source)
    at com.cisco.launcher.s$2.a(Unknown Source)
    at com.cisco.launcher.g$2.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Perhaps i blocked this ip somewhere without my attention, where can i find if the `ASA` ip is blocked from `jre` ?

Can some one help me ?

Thank you

ASDM 7.1 (1)
Windows seven 64 bit
Many jre/jdk 6

Comment: Can you try 32 bit java? 64 bit always causes issues for me...

Comment: @GerryEgan This what i did, i used 32bit java as you can see on my answer.

Comment: Sorry, i meant on my question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just deleted the ASDM cache and everything goes ok.

Cache path:

```
%USERPROFILE%\.asdm
```

Answer (score 1):

Java 7 doesn't work with the ASDM launcher. Java 6 does. A workaround is to browse to the Cisco ASA's IP address... https://ip.of.asa

From there, you can run the ASDM as a "Web Start" application. Don't bother with the ASDM launcher.

[image]

Comment: But, i'm not using java7 !?